# Assigning list to dropdown inside subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to populate an `NgMultiSelectDropDown` using some data fetched from database using subscribe method. The list to be assigned to the dropdown is being populated inside the subscribe method.

```
a = [];
ddlList = [];
public jsonString: string = "";
public insrdList: Array < InsuredData > = [];
public insrdList1: InsuredData[];
constructor(
  http: HttpClient,
  @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string,
  private _cmsService: CMSService) {
  http.get < WeatherForecast[] > (baseUrl +
    'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
    this.forecasts = result;
  }, error => console.error(error));
  this._cmsService.getAllInsuredNames().subscribe(res => {
    var i = 0;
    for (var k in res) {
      i++;
      this.ddlList.push(
        {
          "item_id": i,
          "item_text": (res)[k].insuredName
        }
      };
    }
    this.a = this.ddlList;
  }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

My issue is that when I am trying to bind the `dropdown` to `ddlList`, it doesn't work. But, when I bind it to `a`, it works.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'" [data]="a" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MultiSelectComponent` applies `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. It works by comparing references of the inputs of the component. In the case of `ddlList` you didn't change the reference to the object (array in javascript is object), and the OnPush change detector did not get triggered. In the case of `a`, the reference for array `a` was changed in this part:

```
this.a = this.ddlList;
```

Comment: got it..so is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'd use `spread sintax`. It's useful in the cases like this. `this.ddlList = [ ...this.ddlList, {"item_id": i, "item_text": (res)[k].insuredName} ]`

Comment: Got it to work using ChangeDetectorRef’s markForCheck method as suggested in this article - https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/